# create table with loop in Php

Tags: php, html, loops

What I want is show the total clicks per `Category id` of the items only for 20 items order by the highest total clicks per day.

Now I am using hard code and the result have to looks like this

[image: i am using hard code to t]

So, if the `item id` and `total clicks` already fill up the

> 20columns (for item id and total clicks) + 2 for the tittle so means
>
> 22columns

It has to move to next row.

Because I am referring to my db, so I am using loop to create the table, and when I doing that way, I am getting this result....

[image]

> The result will keep showing until the end in the left side. Thats very hard to read for report purposes. I wanted the result looks like the first figure that I've uploaded.

Here is what I am doing now:

```
  include "Con.php";
        //get the value from Get Method 
        $CatidValue = $_GET['CatIds'];
        //(The date format would looks like yyyy-mm-dd)
        $DateFrom = $_GET['DateFrom'];  
        $DateTo = $_GET['DateTo'];
        //select the CatID
        $SqlGet= "Select CatId from try where CatId = $CatidValue";
        $_SqlGet = mysqli_query($connection,$SqlGet);
        $TakeResultGet = mysqli_fetch_array($_SqlGet);
        $CatIdTittle = $TakeResultGet ['CatId'];

        echo"
            For Category Id : $CatIdTittle
            <br>
                    
        ";
        
        //For Loop purpose and break the value
        $explodeValueFrom = explode("-",$DateFrom);
        $explodeValueTo = explode("-",$DateTo);
        $DateValueFrom = $explodeValueFrom[0].$explodeValueFrom[1].$explodeValueFrom[2];
        $DateValueTo = $explodeValueTo[0].$explodeValueTo[1].$explodeValueTo[2];    
        
        //Loop through the date
        for($Loop=$DateValueFrom; $Loop <= $DateValueTo; $Loop++){
            $YearLoop= substr($Loop, 0,4);
            $MonthLoop =substr($Loop, 4,2);
            $DayLoop = substr($Loop, 6,2);

            $DateTittleValue = $YearLoop."-".$MonthLoop."-".$DayLoop;
            $trValue = "<th class='tg-amwm' colspan='2'>$DateTittleValue</th>";

                
                echo"
                <table class='tg'>
                    <tr>
                        $trValue
                    </tr>
                ";
                echo"
                <table class='tg'>
                    <tr>
                        <td class='tg-yw4l'>Items Id</td>
                        <td class='tg-yw4l'>Total Clicks</td>
                    </tr>
                ";
            
        
            
            //to get the item id and total clicks
            $SqlSelect = "select `Item Id`,`Total Clicks`,Day from try where CatId = $CatidValue and Day = '$DateTittleValue' ORDER BY `try`.`Total Clicks`  DESC limit 20";
            $_SqlSelect = mysqli_query($connection,$SqlSelect);
            foreach ($_SqlSelect as $ResultSelect) {
                $Day = $ResultSelect['Day'];
                $ItemId = $ResultSelect['Item Id'];
                $TotalClicks = $ResultSelect['Total Clicks'];

                echo"       
                    <tr>
                        <td class='tg-yw4l'>$ItemId</td>
                        <td class='tg-yw4l'>$TotalClicks</td>
                    </tr>               
                ";
            }
        }           
    ?>
```

Comment: You can achieve that with the help of CSS and some float magic. Just place each of those tables inside a div, and make them float to the left.

Comment: @LeonelAtencio "Float Magic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to float each table with the float:left css property and some percentage based on the number of tables you want on the same row. In this case, 33% will do. Take a look at this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgXqPk

The magic happens on:

```
.tg {
  width: 33%;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: You are the best ! this is the answer

Comment: Glad i helped. If this answer it for you, please accept it!.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add **td** dynamically within a table for each day report ( data should be grouped by date).

Comment: what you are saying was right, but the answer from @Leonel Atencio is suitable for my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
you can try i hope this perfect for you to draw a table using PHP Loop.
<?php  
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>"; 
for ($row=1; $row <= 10; $row++) { 
echo "<tr> \n";
for ($col=1; $col <= 10; $col++) { 
$p = $col * $row;
echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
 }
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```